# opencv sift algorithm, how to get confidence from findHomography

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I am trying to create an application for iPhone, but I am a new developer for both openCV and iOS. I have more than 50 object images, I have one scene image from camera. In each time I have one of these objects in the scene. I could find a single object via sift algorithm, but I couldnt find a way to calculate confidence to compare with between objects, because some objects are very similar. I used findHomography function, but still no idea  how to get the confidence. I find this from openCV library,

```
    struct CV_EXPORTS MatchesInfo
{
    MatchesInfo();
    MatchesInfo(const MatchesInfo &other);
    const MatchesInfo& operator =(const MatchesInfo &other);

    int src_img_idx, dst_img_idx;       // Images indices (optional)
    std::vector<DMatch> matches;
    std::vector<uchar> inliers_mask;    // Geometrically consistent matches mask
    int num_inliers;                    // Number of geometrically consistent matches
    Mat H;                              // Estimated homography
    double confidence;                  // Confidence two images are from the same panorama
};
```

but I dont know how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a few examples of images that you work with.  SIFT may or may not be appropriate for what you're trying to do.  There're a lot of different approaches for this task.

Please note that homography is P2 to P2 invertible mapping, which basically means that it's precise for planar objects (or for the scenes far away) and since your objects are (probably) not planar its an approximation.

You could probably come up with a lot of ways to measure this confidence.  Basically what's important is the support of the homography (i.e. how many points were chosen by RANSAC out of all of the SIFT matches that you had to compute the homography) and how well these 'inlier' points are mapped by the homography.  To find thescore, use the homography to project the points onto the second image and find the cumulative distance of reprojections from the original points.  The lower the score, the better the match (note that you'd need to normalize by the number of points, since otherwise for a smaller number of correspondences you'd get a better score, which is not what you want)

Hope this helps,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find confidence between objects. I thought these following steps would help:

(because you mentioned homography matrix, so i think it's planar object)

1. abstract sift keypoint from each planar object image
2. compare the scene image with object image by matching keypoints.
3. For some object images , you can not find a homography matrix between them. but for the others ,that you can find homography matrix between them, transform the object images to scene images by using homogaphy matrix , perhaps related with function warppespective**.
4. then you can use  template matching to find the object inside scene, and also you can get a confidence value.

I hope it could solve your problem.